# Accessing UNC Share from outside domain for file transfer

Tags: vb.net

I have an FTP Server outside of the domain (In a workgroup). I need to move files using an application called by the FTP client on the FTP server to a share within the domain using VB.net:

(System.IO.File.Move(SourcePath & Filename, TargetPath & Filename))

Impersonation will not work neither will mapping a drive (As no user will be logged on)
This is a console application that takes the above parameters.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What account will the .net application be running in?

Comment: Is the FTP server behind the same router/switch or is it connected to the domain via VPN?

Comment: The application will be called by the FTP app, which is a service running as Local System. The Server is on the same netword but outside of the firewall, although access has been allowed for UNC file sharing providing an authenticated account is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use [NetUseAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370645%28VS.85%29.aspx). Here's a CodeProject article that describes how to use it for something similar to your requirements at least: [Connect to a UNC Path with Credentials](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ConnectUNCPathCredentials.aspx)